# Get template part vs locate template function

Tags: templates, get-template-part

I'm in single.php where I'm trying to get related-posts.php template. The problem is that when using [get template part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) the related-posts.php isn't getting custom taxonomy name from single.php in `wp_Query`.

The solution is getting the wp post terms once again in related-posts.php in order to use `get_template_part`. But technically it shouldn't be required since parent (single.php) is already having it.

But when I use [locate template function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) it works fine. I feel that this method would be slower than `get_template_part`. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all note that [`get_template_part` internally uses `locate_template`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f50d5233f3a45679c1ca903536d932eba305986c/wp-includes/general-template.php#L158), so your feeling that the latter is slower is wrong.

If you look at the code, `get_template_part` is little more than a wrapper for `locate_template`, so if one work and the other not, there are 2 possibilities:

- you are using `get_template_part` wrong
- there's some hook on `"get_template_part_{$slug}"` action that prevent it works

However, if `locate_template` works, use it: it's not slower, to be honest it can be pretty faster if there are functions hooked on `"get_template_part_{$slug}"` that slow down execution.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll now use `locate_template` EVERYWHERE :D