# Loading page template into shortcode

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode, page-template

I am attempting to load a page template into a shortcode so I can easily load the content wherever I want.

I have done some research and many people have said this code has worked for them but for some reason this does not seem to load my template right as I just get a blank page.

I know the shortcode is executing as it does not show as plain text so I'm guessing there is a problem with the way I am loading the template.

Any help is much appreciated .

```
public function register(){
        add_shortcode( 'sponsor_main_page', array($this,'my_form_shortcode') );
            $RegistrationFormId = esc_attr( get_option( 'ik_form_id' ) );
        }

function my_form_shortcode() {
        ob_start();
        get_template_part( 'template-sponsors.php' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) takes slug as first parameter and not filename.

So it should be:

```
get_template_part( 'template-sponsors' );
```

And with more details... This function takes two parameters:

get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null )

And inside of it, the name of a file is built like this:

```
if ( '' !== $name )
```

$templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
 
    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";

So, as you can see, the `.php` part is added automatically. So your code will try to load file called `template-sponsors.php.php` and there is no such file, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely to be occurring because you are adding .php to the parameter in `get_template_part()`. This is how I would write the code for your question:

**Prerequisites for this example to work:**

- Create a folder in your theme directory called `template-parts`.
- Create a new file in this directory called `template-sponsors.php`
- This is assuming your shortcode is `[sponsor_main_page]`

**Code to put in your functions.php:**

```
function custom_theme_load_sponsors_template() {
  ob_start();
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/template-sponsors' ); 
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'sponsor_main_page', 'custom_theme_load_sponsors_template' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I like using `locate_template`, rather than `get_template_part` . The `locate_template` will do the equivalent of a PHP `include()` or `include_once()`, which is what I think you are aiming for.

```
locate_template("mycustomfunctions.php",true,true);
```

Put your `mycustomfunctions.php` file in the active template folder (optimally, a Child Theme). Then put the `locate_template()` command in your template, at the very top (after the comment block). Any functions in your `mysustomfunctions.php` file will then be available to your template.

The `locate_template` function is called by `get_template_part`. But the parameters allow you to define *how* the include works. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/ for more info.

(**Added** See the accepted answer to this question: [Get template part vs locate template function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/146134/get-template-part-vs-locate-template-function) .  )

Comment: Not sure why the downvote; see the last paragraph of my answer. The locate_template is useful when you want to include a functions-type file (a file of functions that are needed, but you don't need to be loaded on every page as they would be with putting the functions in the functions.php file). See the accepted answer to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/146134/get-template-part-vs-locate-template-function .